# Ubuntu Minecraft server says eula isn't true but is

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 2GB VPS. Whenever I run `java -Xmx1500M -Xms1500M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui` with the eula true it says:

```
[17:56:52] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.8.1
[17:56:52] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[17:56:52] [Server thread/INFO]: You need to agree to the EULA in order to run the server. Go to eula.txt for more info.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Stop server program
2. Remove eula.txt
3. Start server program (generates new eula)
4. Edit eula.txt to say `EULA=TRUE` and SAVE it.
5. DONE!